# why does the Shader Which I created gets purple when I add another image texture to the randomizer?

Tags: shaders, shader-nodes

HYi,
I have a decent amount of Tv screens in the scene for which I have created a shader. Also I randomized the image texture inputs to display different videos on them. So, as you can see in the pictures there is a node group which I have shown with arrows. you can see this node group in the fourth picture. Everything is normal and I can add different videos to the image textures until a specefic numbers of videos. Then when I add another video, the shader turns purple.
Is there is  posiiblty that ther would be a limit for the input?

thanks alot for taking your time
I really appreciate it

[image: when shader turns purple]

[image: normal]

[image: Main nodes with the node group highlighted with arrows]

[image: The node group with the image texture highlighted with an arrow]

Comment: Hi :). Yes. Eevee has a hard limit on the amout of textures/shaders that can be inside one material. But this may also be caused by low memory - consider lowering the input resolution.

Comment: Ooof... I've done something similar, but I had less (about 20?) videos, and made them only about 10 seconds long... It was still brutal to wait for all videos to load on each frame, maybe it's optimized now.

Comment: Thank you guys, It was actually true

Comment: Consider merging all the videos into a single video, or at least a few videos, and then access them by positioning your UVs where the video is supposed to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much for your help guys,
As you said the problem was caused because of the limit which Eevee has on calculation multiple textures.(more than it can handle). Also it wasn't because of low memory it was just because eevee is not optimized for very high amount of textures. Blender version 3.3.1